# What would be a compact way to return 1 if a variable is 0 and to return 0 if it is 1?

Tags: python, boolean

How could the following be made more compact (perhaps using Booleans), given that I am supplied with an integer variable?

```
indexTag = 0 # or 1
1 if indexTag == 0 else 0
```

Comment: I dunno if to put as answer but `[1,0][indexTag]` works as well

Comment: That has the merit (or demerit) of raising an IndexError exception should any invalid integer ever try to crash the party.

Comment: Could you give some more context? What are you actually *doing* with the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `not`:

```
not indexTag
```

which gives you a *boolean* (`True` or `False`), but Python booleans are a subclass of `int` and do have an integer value (`False` is `0`, `True` is `1`). You could turn that back into an integer with `int(not indexTag)` but if this is just a boolean, why bother?

Or you could subtract from 1; `1 - 0` is `1`, and `1 - 1` is `0`:

```
1 - indexTag
```

or you could use a conditional expression:

```
0 if indexTag else 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> for indexTag in (0, 1):
...     print 'indexTag:', indexTag
...     print 'boolean not:', not indexTag
...     print 'subtraction:', 1 - indexTag
...     print 'conditional expression:', 0 if indexTag else 1
...     print
... 
indexTag: 0
boolean not: True
subtraction: 1
conditional expression: 1

indexTag: 1
boolean not: False
subtraction: 0
conditional expression: 0
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, so spell it out? Either `not bool(indexTag)` or `int( not bool(indexTag) )`. Think I prefer the conditional expression to either.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and detailed suggestion. The key bit of information is the fact that the Python Boolean values can be converted directly into integer representations.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `^` ([XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table)) and simply:

```
indexTag = 1 ^ indexTag
```

This achieves what you want because.. that's what XOR does:

```
+---------------+
| Input | Output|
+---+---+-------+ 
| A | B |       |
+---+---+       |
| 0 | 0 |   0   |  
| 0 | 1 |   1   |   <
| 1 | 0 |   1   |
| 1 | 1 |   0   |   <
+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: True, just as long as your indexTag really is constrained to be 1 or 0. As soon as a 2 sneaks past your defences, things go downhill.

Comment: @nigel222 True.. But this is what OP wrote in his title, so I assume that's that case.

Comment: As I said, xor not wrong. It's just instinct to consider the possibility of bad input, and using a somewhat obscure mapping of one integer onto another when that happens might prove "unhelpful". (I did rather like Bhargav's suggestion, `[1,0][i]` manages to raise an exception if the spec is wrong, using just five extra keystrokes).